# Adding an integer to all values in a tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples

What is the recommended/most pythonic way of editing a tuple in code like that shown below?

```
tup_list = [(1, 2), (5, 0), (3, 3), (5, 4)]
max_tup = max(tup_list)
my_tup1 = (max_tup[0] + 1, max_tup[1] + 1)
my_tup2 = tuple(map(lambda x: x + 1, max_tup))
my_tup3 = max([(x+1, y+1) for (x, y) in tup_list])
```

Which of the three methods above is preferred, or is there a better way to do this? (Should of course return `(6, 5)` in this example).

There is a temptation to do something like

```
my_tup = max(tup_list)[:] + 1
```

or

```
my_tup = max(tup_list) + (1, 1)
```

however neither of these work obviously.

Comment: The first one seems like the most readable one. You should also test the speeds with the `timeit` module, which I presume will give close results.

Comment: @Rockybilly I would agree. Speed is not a concern in this case.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use a generator expression with `tuple`:

```
my_tup = tuple(x+1 for x in max_tup)
# or my_tup = tuple(x+1 for x in max(tup_list))
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, felt like I must be missing something!

Answer (score 2):

```
my_tup1 = (max_tup[0] + 1, max_tup[1] + 1)
```

Straight-forward and easy to read. The parentheses explicitly indicate that a tuple will be created and + indicates that numbers will be modified. Therefore it also seems pythonic.

```
my_tup2 = tuple(map(lambda x: x + 1, max_tup))
```

Takes a functional approach, but a tuple is abused as list and finally it is converted back to a tuple. Not straight-forward to someone that does not know how python's tuples work.

```
my_tup3 = max([(x+1, y+1) for (x, y) in tup_list])
```

Uses the invariant that the maximum remains the same if all values are incremented by 1. So you need to wrap your head around it and this code does more work than any other approach.

So I would go for the first approach.